# .Net 3.5 NameSpace Problem?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Got an asp.net 3.5 app - compiles fine, but when browse to page I get the error below.
Searches for this all seem to indicate it is a namespace problem, but all of my pages seem to declare the proper namespace.
Any assistance appreciated!

Phil J.

### Server Error in '/Internet/bm2/bm2' Application.

Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: 'bm2.PolicyLookup' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.Page'.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="PolicyLookup.aspx.vb" Inherits="bm2.PolicyLookup"  validateRequest="false" aspcompat="true"%>
Line 2:
Line 3:

Source File: /internet/bm2/bm2/policylookup.aspx    Line: 1

=======
The System.Web.UI.Page is indeed inherited from in the code-behind:

Namespace bm2
    Public Class PolicyLookup
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
        Protected WithEvents lblResponse As Label
        Protected WithEvents btnSubmit As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button
        Dim myModel As New bm2.Model
        Dim postData
        Public objMessage

Comment: Is the PolicyLookup class derived from Page?  The error message says it isn't.

Comment: your code behind is probably missing Inherits Page

Comment: Well the code behind does inherit from System.Web.IU.Page:Namespace bm2
    Public Class PolicyLookup
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
        Protected WithEvents lblResponse As Label
        Protected WithEvents btnSubmit As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button
        Dim myModel As New bm2.Model
        Dim postData
        Public objMessage

Comment: Please don't paste code in the comments - its unreadable. Could you update your question instead?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a namespace problem (very unlikely), you'll either need to add an `@import` statement to your page:

```
<%@ Import namespace=”My.Namespace.Where.bm2.PolicyLookup.Exists” %>
```

**or** modify your `@Page` directive to include the fully-qualified class name

```
....inherits="My.Namespace.bm2.PolicyLookup"
```

Of course, this only works if `bm2.PolicyLookup` descends from `System.Web.UI.Page`.

The @Page attribute

```
inherits="bm2.PolicyLookup"
```

tells ASP.NET that the class `bm2.PolicyLookup` inherits from `System.Web.UI.Page`, and that it should be instantiated when processing the page to handle `on_load()`, `render()`, etc events. However, ASP.NET believes that your class `bm2.PolicyLookup` does not inherit from System.Web.UI.Page, thus the error.

In order for the webforms engine to be able to process your page, it has to descend from the existing Page class. That class provides all of the event handlers, rendering methods etc. that are required.

*Also, a bit of unrelated advice: Visual Studio hides a lot of functionality when working with a VB.Net site. Consider moving to C#, and to a web application project instead of a website project.*

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a PolicyLookup class in System.Web (I don't think there is), but I ran into a similar problem when I tried to name a page SiteMap.aspx, since there was a type named SiteMap (though it was in a different namespace, it still seemed to cause a problem).  The fix was to either rename completely, or have the code behind class name be prefixed with an underscore (you may have to update the Page directive in your aspx to match the new type name.

Comment: if you use the fully-qualified class name there shouldn't be any namespace confusion.

Comment: I tried renaming class to _PolicyLookup and the page directive to reference bm2._PolicyLookup, but get same error.   Changed it back.

Comment: Public class PolicyLookup is in namespace bm2 and inherits System.Web.UI.Page.  So I am stumped as to what it thinks the error is

Comment: Have you tried changing the name of the aspx file itself?  Those pages do get compiled into code, that could be the conflict.  If that doesn't solve the problem, then I'm stumped as well.